# How write JQuery function in kendo ui template?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I really don't know that is `kendo ui` support for this.

I wanna write a `JQuery` function in the `kendo ui` template

Here is the example

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="someId">
#
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#textfield1').attr('required');

});
#
<script>
```

the thing is the hash("#") mark gives me a error because kendo ui using hash mark to separate JavaScript and HTML in kendo UI. 
So how can I add hash mark in above example.
Can some one help me ??

Comment: the hash mark in front if the textfield1 id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a backslash as an escape character:

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h4>#= $("\#theSpan").text()  #</h4>
</script>
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/awAru)**

P.S. I don't think you need the document.ready as the KendoUI code (including templates) depends on jQuery and only runs after the document is ready.

Comment: Thanks bro. you save my life

Comment: @NoughT, you are welcome. See my update about not using document.ready.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put every code line with the opening and closing #.

```
#$(document).ready(function () {#
    #$('#textfield1').attr('required');#
 #}); #
```

Source: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/expressions

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is incorrect ! here is correct one

here is the example too

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/expressions

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="someId">

# $(document).ready(function () { #

#  $('#textfield1').attr('required'); #

# });#

<script>
```